# RestyGwt ResponseFormatException when Return Value is String

Tags: gwt, jersey, jax-rs

gwt 2.5 with Jersey 1.17 and RestyGWT 1.3

when i call it from client i get an error:
Resposne was not an valid JASON document

it works with Integer but why not with Strings???

my resource:

```
@Path("/files")
public class FileResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/backup")
    public String getBackup() {
        return new String("asd");
    }
```

and RestService interface:

```
public interface FileRestService extends RestService {

    @GET
    @Path("/backup")
    void getBackup(MethodCallback<String> callback);


    /**
     * Utility class to get the instance of the Rest Service
     */

    public static final class Util {

        private static FileRestService instance;

        public static final FileRestService get() {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = GWT.create(FileRestService.class);
                ((RestServiceProxy) instance).setResource(new Resource(GWT
                        .getHostPageBaseURL() + "rest/files"));
            }
            return instance;
        }

        private Util() {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that JSON, per spec, requires an object or array at the top-level (`JSON.parse()` in JavaScript has a relaxed parser that also accepts strings, numbers, booleans and `null`).

Comment: hm ok it works with return new String("'asd'");

Comment: I suspect Jersey's JSON support to treat a `String` return value as containing the JSON. Note that `'asd'` is not valid JSON either: string literals have to be quoted with double-quotes in JSON, not with apostrophes. See http://json.org

Answer (score 0):

i solved it with a MessageBodyWriter which sets the String in quotes

```
package digitronic.ems.server.filebrowser;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import org.json.JSONObject;

@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class StringProvider implements MessageBodyWriter<String> {

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return type == String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(String t, Class<?> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return t.length();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(String t, Class<?> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders,
            OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException,
            WebApplicationException {
        if (mediaType.toString().equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)) {
            String wr = JSONObject.quote(t);
            entityStream.write(wr.getBytes());
        }
    }
}
```